# What is the geometric interpretation of the normal equations $\mathbf{N}={{\mathbf{A}}^{T}}\mathbf{A}$ matrix when the columns of A are orthogonal?

Tags: geometry, least-squares, svd, parameter-estimation, homogeneous-equation

I have a homogeneous problem with the form $\mathbf{A}_{n\times6}\mathbf{x}_{6\times1}=\mathbf{0}_{n\times1}$ in which the columns of the $\mathbf{A}$ are orthogonal in each row, for example

$\mathbf{A}=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   \vdots  & \vdots   \\
   {{\mathbf{a}}_{i}^T} & {{\mathbf{b}}_{i}}^T  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots   \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

with, $\mathbf{a}_{i}^{T}{{\mathbf{b}}_{i}}=0$ for each row in $\mathbf{A}$.
This results in a

$\mathbf{N}={{\mathbf{A}}^{T}}\mathbf{A}=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1  \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

This structure is unique and results in three non-zero singular values out of six.

I am finding it hard to understand the geometric meaning of this problem and would appreciate any help or direction (literature) to understand it.